# Copy text snippets one-by-one from table in wikipedia article

Tags: windows-7

I'd like a solution that allows me to copy the contents of the ISBN column in [a wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SF_Masterworks#Numbered_paperback_series_.281999-2009.29) to the clipboard one-by-one using a keyboard shortcut. I have AutoHotKey installed (not in relation to this problem) if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** See **Copy ISBN Directly to Clipboard** below for the new code.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/4012426).

---

## Show Prompt to Copy

You could use this JavaScript code:

```js
var textIndex = 0;
jQuery("table.wikitable:nth-child(9)").after("<button type='button' onclick='copyText()'>Get Next ISBN</button>");
function copyText() {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", jQuery("table.wikitable:nth-child(9) tr td:nth-of-type(4) a").eq(textIndex).text() );
    textIndex++;
}
```

It creates a button at the bottom of the table.

Each time,

1. Tab over to the webpage (e.g. using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
2. Click the button. A prompt comes up.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close the prompt.

It's not the most efficient, but it works.

To use this code:

1. Open your browser's console, e.g. by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.
2. Navigate to the `Console` tab, if it's not already selected.
3. Paste it in the box.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

## Copy ISBN Directly to Clipboard

The new code copies the ISBN on button click, reducing the number of steps. (Leave out the `var textIndex = 0;` line if you don't want to lose your place.) It only works in some browsers, though; I tested it on Chrome 45.0.2454.85. According to the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/4012426), it should work on Google Chrome 44, Firefox 42.0a1 and IE 11.0.8600.17814.

```js
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");

  //
  // *** This styling is an extra step which is likely not required. ***
  //
  // Why is it here? To ensure:
  // 1. the element is able to have focus and selection.
  // 2. if element was to flash render it has minimal visual impact.
  // 3. less flakyness with selection and copying which **might** occur if
  //    the textarea element is not visible.
  //
  // The likelihood is the element won't even render, not even a flash,
  // so some of these are just precautions. However in IE the element
  // is visible whilst the popup box asking the user for permission for
  // the web page to copy to the clipboard.
  //

  // Place in top-left corner of screen regardless of scroll position.
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style.top = 0;
  textArea.style.left = 0;

  // Ensure it has a small width and height. Setting to 1px / 1em
  // doesn't work as this gives a negative w/h on some browsers.
  textArea.style.width = '2em';
  textArea.style.height = '2em';

  // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
  textArea.style.padding = 0;

  // Clean up any borders.
  textArea.style.border = 'none';
  textArea.style.outline = 'none';
  textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';

  // Avoid flash of white box if rendered for any reason.
  textArea.style.background = 'transparent';


  textArea.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);

  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}

var textIndex = 0;
jQuery('table.wikitable:nth-child(9)').after('<button type="button" onclick="copyISBN()">Get Next ISBN</button>');
function copyISBN() {
  copyTextToClipboard(jQuery('table.wikitable:nth-child(9) tr td:nth-of-type(4) a').eq(textIndex).text());
  textIndex++;
}
```

Each time,

1. Tab over to the webpage (e.g. using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
2. Click the button or press <kbd>Space</kbd> if the button is already focused. The ISBN is automatically copied to your clipboard.

It doesn't work by key shortcut, but at least it copies for you.

Comment: Thanks! This works a lot better than manually selecting it.

Comment: I get the error "Oops, unable to copy" with the second lot of code in Firefox 40.0.3 (stable) so it looks like I need to wait for 41 to come into the stable branch. Until then, I can use chrome.